# Next.js server-side redirect does not refresh iframe src

Tags: redirect, next.js, server-side

I have a `Next.js` app running in an iframe. My setup works like this:

- The app is opened on `route-a`.
- In the `getServerSideProps` of `route-a` I make some processing and, if conditions are met, I reroute to `route-b` by returning `{ redirect: { destination: 'route-b', permanent: false } }`.
- The loaded content is indeed that of `route-b`.
- However, if I inspect the page, the `src` of the `iframe` is still `route-a`.

Is this intended? Is there any way to force-refresh of the iframe src?

Comment: These routes don't contain iframes, but rather these are loaded in an iframe - e.g. <iframe src="route-a" />. When I run the application in a browser as stand-alone, the redirect updates the url in the browser's address bar. However, when I run the application in an iframe, the `src` is not getting updated.